# What kind of man am I?

Tags: riddle

In voice I exit in light

In fists I carry a stick

My neighbour I fight

And cars I hold 'em

I am a ____man

**Hint:**

> Perhaps you shouldn't think of me as one man, but many men with one name / The same name used by different characters

**Hint2:**

> I exit in light, when did I go in?

Comment: " but many men with one name" -> Sharing the same name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are a...

> sandman

In voice I exit in light

> From the song *Enter Sandman*, the chorus goes: "Exit: light / Enter: night"

In fists I carry a stick

> The wrestler known as The Sandman carries a kendo stick.

My neighbour I fight

> A reference to Marvel's Sandman, one of (your friendly neighborhood) Spiderman's nemeses. (Thanks to @Nathaniel)

And cars I hold 'em

> The Holden Sandman is a well-known model of panel van.

Comment: Who's your friendly neighborhood?

Comment: From Oak's comment above, the "neighbour" clue might refer to the Marvel character Sandman, who is an enemy of Spider-Man, as in friendly neighbourhood Spider-Man.

Comment: Great answer! I'm convinced this is going to be marked correct when you incorporate Nathaniel's clue. I was totally stumped on the "voice" part of the first clue. And Metallica used to be my favorite band. Doh!

Comment: @TTT Precisely; But SHAME for you not getting that reference when you first read it :P

Answer (score 10):

I am a

> Caveman

In voice I exit in light

> I walk out of the dark cave into the daylight.

In fists I carry a stick

> I carry a club.

My neighbour I fight

> My neighbor tried to take my food, and my wife.

And cars I hold 'em

> 15 minutes could save you 15% or more on car insurance. It's so easy even a caveman can do it!

Answer (score 9):

You could be a

> Snowman

You exit in light because

> you melt in the sun

Your fist carry sticks because

> your arms are made of sticks

You fight your neighbor because

> neighbors have snowball fights (This one's a stretch)

You hold cars because

> Snow causes traffic, accidents, you can get snowed in, etc.

Comment: Great first post. =D

Comment: Haha thanks! You think it's right?

Comment: I think some of it's a stretch, but it has potential =D

Answer (score 5):

You could be a

> Policeman

In voice I exit in light

> Just picture all the movie scenes where the criminal has flashlights, car lights, police-car-flashing-lights, helicopter lights, etc. shining on them, and the policeman is speaking to them from behind the lights (e.g., "Come out with your hands up!")

In fists I carry a stick

> A policeman carries a baton

My neighbor I fight

> A policeman may have to fight with another in the line of duty

And cars I hold 'em

> A policeman may impound a car used for illegal activity

Comment: The type of person that you mention can also stop traffic.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha true, that's probably a better, more specific relation to the riddle

Comment: It is not policeman; However it is an interesting attempt. I edited in an hint

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kind of similar to answer of elmer007, but I'll give it a shot.

You are a:

> Red traffic light man (The guy symbol on traffic lights)

In voice I exit in light

> When green light flashes, red guy dims out and all waiting drivers beep horn (in voice).

In fists I carry a stick

> Believe it or not, red guy carries the traffic light pole (a big stick).

My neighbour I fight

> Red guy and green guy always fight to dim the other one and show up.

And cars I hold 'em

> Red guy stops traffic sometimes.